# Conditional jump out of range in 8086 assembly

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I'm coding in assembly for Intel 8086 under TASM in DosBox and the problem I frequently stumble upon is getting the compilation error of "Relative jump out of range by *some* bytes" where my conditional jumps are.

Now, I know that conditional jumps are short jumps but is there any way to somehow... "stretch" them? :) I know I can place intermediate jumps or try to assemble the code so that the jumps are in reach but as my program grows larger, I think the latter option may prove to be less valid than now.

Can I somehow tell the compiler to make something with it or can I somehow tweak my jumps?

Comment: \*cough\* University curriculum \*cough\*

Comment: The problem of programmers writing big blobs of code is however time-less.  You are not using CALL enough.

Comment: Look at your assembler options.  Most of them have an option you can flip to automatically generate a relative jump to a far jump as necessary and then (other than the performance impact) you don't have to think about it anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's been a long time since I've done any assembly coding, but as I recall, the usual way to "stretch" a conditional jump is to invert the logic of the test and place an absolute jump representing the branch you want to take just after the conditional jump.

Comment: Thank you for your reply but could you please elaborate? Say I have a loop label CALLed with logic like: <someOperations>, JLE return, <someOperations,> JMP self. I can't really invert the logic by placing a traditional JMP here since the test has to be performed and the result checked to know if the loop should break.

Comment: Like I said, it's been a while, but I think you'd turn that into <someOperations>, JG skip, JMP return, skip: <someOperations,> JMP self

Answer (score 0):

Another way was to put a "table" of jumps within reach, then you relative jumped to to the jump you wanted to jump to. :)

You could get clever with that and change the jump in the table. Course debugging such code was 'erm "fun"..

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Surely the debugging was a nightmare, that's why I wanted to stay away from any midpoint creating-based solution :)